# OWA error "OpenIdConnectIdpException"

Tags: microsoft-office-365, entra-id

As of ~2018/07/10, attempting to sign in to https://outlook.office365.com using any MFA-enforced, AD-synced O365 accounts and any web browser on any device on any network doesn't prompt for the TOTP and, instead, fails with the following error message:

```
:-(
Something went wrong
We can't get that information right now. Please try again later.
X-ClientId: E69D5A6642C242AC9C337AF8EC04AC95
request-id 19bf2ff2-1040-4772-b207-487b71b0adef
X-Auth-Error OpenIdConnect Microsoft.Exchange.Security.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectIdpException
X-OWA-Version 15.20.973.23
X-FEServer DB6PR04CA0014
X-BEServer CWXP265MB0983
Date:27/07/2018 13:59:39
```

[image]

An exception to this is that, on Windows PCs, Microsoft's web browsers (Internet Explorer and Microsoft Edge) offer "Connected to Windows" sign-in options which work fine, presumably because they skip the MFA / TOTP step due to a previous successful and Windows-registered sign-in.

[image]

MFA-enforced, in-cloud O365 accounts are unaffected.

The Office 365 Admin Center’s service health and Azure AD Connect's Synchronization Service Manager both report no problems / errors.

Apps (Microsoft Outlook, Skype for Business, etc) connected to the affected O365 accounts continue to work but attempting to sign into new ones simply re-prompts for the password.

Literally the only things that I've managed to find online are the following none of which were helpful, hence this post:

1. https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_o365admin-mso_dirservices-mso_o365b/issue-with-office-365-azure-login/a8509ab6-201c-49dc-8112-9f574072482a
2. https://www.erroraway.com/Questions-and-Discussions/201804/12/a8509ab6-201c-49dc-8112-9f574072482a.html / https://www.dllrepairfree.com/201805/31/a8509ab6-201c-49dc-8112-9f574072482a.html
3. https://twitter.com/alnsportsmouth/status/983615870915100672

Comment: If you havent already raised a support ticket, you should do so. The fact that the error is from Exchange Online (EXO) and not Azure AD (AAD) means token issuance from AAD worked. What happens if you use private mode in same browser on the same device where failures occur?

Comment: @maweeras Yeah, I have. I just thought I'd post this so, whoever offers the solution, it's posted publicly. Same thing in private browsing mode.

Comment: Based on that screenshot for Edge/W10 does that work? if yes, is the machine hybrid AAD joined and are you login in with a Hello for Business credential? Can you be clearer with regards to what works/doesn't with details on OS (W7/W8.1/W10/other), browser name (IE/Edge/Chrome/Firefox) , browser mode (private/normal), whether AAD registered or not, is a PRT present, Is hello 4 business used for interactive logon (in case of W10) to PC etc.

Comment: @maweeras Yes, Edge and IE work.The PCs are joined to the AD domain and synced via AADC. No Windows Hello for Business. As I said, any browser on any device. I'm not sure what PRT is.

Comment: PRT is primary refresh token. See www.jairocadena.com for details . Can you put case number here?

Comment: @maweeras Will do. It's with our reseller's support at the moment but they always escalate it to Office 365 pretty quickly.

Comment: @maweeras Case number 118073018680481.

Comment: Looks like there are issues with your pass through authentication. Upgrade to the latest version and deploy agent on another machine for resiliency. See https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/connect/active-directory-aadconnect-pass-through-authentication-quick-start

Comment: @maweeras I updated the installation from version 1.1.371.0 to version 1.1.819.0 but it didn't make a difference.
You're correct in that pass-through authentication was enabled - I didn't even know that. We must have been testing it internally and left it enabled.

Comment: Odd that it didnt make a difference because auth was failing when using a browser that tried to do PTA. Thats what logs on this side showed. Anyways Im glad its solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following my comments with @maweeras, I reconfigured Azure AD Connect changing the user sign-in mode from pass-through authentication (we didn't need it) to password hash synchronization which immediately resolved the problem.

**Update: 2018/08/01 15:00**

This morning, out of curiosity, I reconfigured Azure AD Connect changing the user sign-in mode from password hash synchronization back to pass-through authentication which completed with the following status message:

> Pass-through Authentication was successfully enabled, but it appears
>   your network may be blocking certain ports required by the feature to
>   function correctly. We detected the following ports might be blocked
>   on your network: 443

[image]

As advised by https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/81673e69-1220-4231-a9c0-0753f4aa3455/azure-ad-connect-443-may-be-blocked?forum=WindowsAzureAD, on the server, I browsed to https://aadap-portcheck.connectorporttest.msappproxy.net/ which loaded fine and all tests passed.

[image]

In any case, I’m now able to sign-in to Office 365 using the same affected Office 365 user accounts so I don’t know what the original problem was.

Answer (score 1):

I had a couple users that couldn't login to their mailboxes, we recently went to hybrid AD and these had been inactive. When they came back, they were unable to login to their outlook app and to Exchange online, there was this message when logging in to Exchange Online.

***ClientId: 50327C95XXX14F30236CXXX9D request-id 0XXXXXXXXXXX X-Auth-Error OpenIdConnect Microsoft.Exchange.Clients.Security.AccountTerminationException X-OWA-Version 15.20.3021.29 X-FEServer DM3XXXXA0099 X-BEServer DM6PXXXX2666 Date:26/05/2020 15:59:13***

[Error message Exchange Online](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ElhDc.png)

There was also an error in the admin center when selecting the users in question, it said something about a mismatch on the archive GUID.

[ArchiveGUID error in O365 admin center](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NrP4h.jpg)

We tried several things to fix it, one was to take these users out of the Azure AD Connect sync by moving them to the OU set to not sync in the local AD but that caused the cloud accounts to be deleted, after having them restored they would be deleted again, even when the accounts were active, the errors would still be there and I couldn't get those users up and working.

I found nothing in the web and was not contacted by Microsoft support after opening a ticket.  After a while, i found something helpful that gave me an idea and I did this to fix the issues:

I replaced “MsExchArchiveGUID” for both users in ADSI Edit in the local AD. To do so, I took the cloud GUID from the error in the admin center and ran in through the power shell commands below to convert them to hex. After I did that, i waited for the changes to be synched to the cloud, then I had to remove the licenses of one of the users for a few minutes and add it back and then it worked, for the other one it worked right away after the sync.

The commands in powershell to convert the cloud GUID in order to replace it in the local AD:

- *[system.guid]$guid = "Cloud archive GUID"*
- *($Guid.ToByteArray() | foreach { $_.ToString('x2') }) -Join ' '*

Answer (score 0):

I performed the following steps below with an account I was getting this error with and it seems to have resolved the issue (with which step, I'm not sure):

1. Converted the mailbox to a shared mailbox in Exchange 365
2. Converted the mailbox back to a user mailbox in Exchange 365
3. Removed and re-added the license in Exchange 365
4. Edit the mailbox in Exchange 365 and in the "Editing Mailbox Window"
   I disabled and re-enabled "Email Connectivity | Outlook on the web"
5. On the Local AD properties of the user
   account on the "**Account**" tab, the "**Log On To...**" was configured to
   logon to specific workstations. I removed all of the workstations and
   toggled the radio button "**All computers**" and saved the AD account

I was then able to login to the mailbox again. Hope this helps someone!